# Exact Target - Google Analytics Integration

Tags: marketing-cloud, google-analytics

Does anyone have a step by step document on how to integrate GA with exact target so UTM parameters are automatically pulled in email links?

Answer (score 2):

Connecting Google Analytics Connector you might be interested in this documentation

[**Web Analytics Connector**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/)

You can also follow these steps if you plan on using the integration

[**Plan for Web Analytics Connector**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/plan_for_web_analytics_integration/)

Hope this helps.